# Using Java split to evaluate a mathematical expression

Tags: java, regex, split, expression

After some time of working with this problem, I'm having trouble figuring out the Regex syntax for exactly what I need.

In a Java course I'm taking, we're given the task of building a calculator capable of taking an expression string (written with or without parentheses) and correctly evaluating it.

The concept behind the parsing of the expression is that you have a string...

`5+16/20-56+7-20*16/9`

And you want to get two ArrayLists via 'split':

`{5,16,20,56,7,20,16,9}`
`{+,/,-,+,-,*,/}`

You then perform operations piece by piece, in order of operation priority, emptying operations from your ArrayList until your number array has one element: the final result.

Unfortunately, I have no experience with `Regex` and can't make *any sense* of the tutorials and examples I'm reading.

I can't figure out how to split based on `"[*-/+]"`, and I can't figure out how to select whole *numbers* to split by rather than mere digits. I can't get my code to compile because of these errors. The one working snippet of code I did get:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String expression = "3+5+6-10*20/150-14+76%2";

//      String[] operands = expression.split("");
        String[] operators = expression.split("[0-9]");

//      System.out.println(operands);
        System.out.println(operators);
    }
}
```

results in

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@308ab721
```

And I have no idea where that comes from.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Or point to a very good *beginner's lesson* on Regex?

I appreciate your help, everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operands` and `operators` is an `array`

to print `array` you can do

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(operands));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(operators));
```

And you should split it like this:

```
String[] operands = expression.split("[\\+\\-\\*\\%\\/]");
String[] operators = expression.split("[0-9]+");
```

Comment: None of the backslashes in the first pattern are necessary, although they're harmless.

Comment: okay, modified it. but Its a good practice to include escape character in regex(for begginner). Since in some case it is a must. `replaceAll()` for example

Comment: I'm sorry, you *do* need \\ before `-` so that it doesn't treat it as a range.  I am not having a good day.  Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: No problem if you know where to put it. p/s: I've been through that situation too :D

Comment: Thanks for this! I don't know how I forgot to match types when printing-- Too out of practice, I guess.

And could you explain how the regex expressions above work? I ended up using `\\d+` and it works the same as your `[0-9]+`, but I have no understanding as to why.

Comment: @jwarner112 Because `\d` (the backslash gets doubled in Java string literals) means "a digit", which is just a shorthand for `[0-9]`.  (Unless there are some other funky Unicode characters that are considered digits...)

Comment: @jwarner112 as ajb pointed, `\d` is the same as `[0-9]` while `\D` is the same as _anything **exlude** `\d`._ You can check [**here**](http://www.regexr.com/) to learn more about regex

Comment: @RafaEl And I presume then that in layman's terms, `+` means "continue this until the sequence breaks"? As in, case the digits until you hit a non-digit?

Comment: @jwarner112 `+` means "one or more".  For many cases, it does mean "continue until the sequence breaks".  But say you used a regex `[0-9]+0` with the input `"123050"`.  This would match, but `[0-9]+` would pick up only five digits, not all six, because the last `0` in the input will match the last `0` in the regex.

Comment: @ajb Ah, I understand this so much better now. Thanks, everyone, for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're printing out the memory address of your variables. If you want a string representation, you may do

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(operators));
```

What's happening behind the scenes is the `println()` method is calling `toString()` on any object that is passed to it. The default implementation of `toString()` for an array in Java to is return the memory address, which is why you get this ugly thing printing out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but this should work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{      
  String expression = "3+5+6-10*20/150-14+76%2";

  String[] operands = expression.split("[-+*%/]");
  String[] operators = expression.split("[0-9]+");

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(operands));
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(operators));
}
```

You need to escape Regex meta-characters (or in this case just change the order), and print your arrays properly.

A little elaboration:

In Regex, certain characters have special meaning. You've used these already by defining the range `0-9`, with the dash being the meta-character. The same applies to `-`. You can see a complete list [here](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php).

I actually made use of the `+` meta-character (which "matches the preceding subexpression one or more times") in the modified number matching pattern to reduce the number of empty strings that split picked up. It does this by matching *one or multiple occurrences* of a digit.

Comment: (1) You do not need to escape most meta-characters when they're inside `[]`.  In particular, `+` and `*` have no special meaning inside square brackets.  (2) If you did escape them, you'd do it with a backslash, not a forward slash.  All you've done here is to put a slash five times in your character class, which is harmless but looks silly.

Comment: @ajb 1 slash is the division operator. And I thought you had to double escape meta-characters, but I was mistaken. Thanks, edited.

Comment: Well, you're down to two redundant slashes, instead of four.

Comment: @ajb There was something tricky here that I failed to catch, and caused me some confusion. Putting the `-` anywhere but last or first inside the `[]` caused an exception. Regex tries to match it as a range. Fixed.

Comment: Darn, I forgot about `-`!!!  That does have special meaning inside `[]`.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply numbers or non numbers, the regex is simple:

```
String[] operands = expression.split("\\D+");
String[] operators = expression.replaceAll("^\\d+", "").split("\\d+");
```

The regex meanings are:

- `\D+` 1 or more non-digits ([see demo](http://rubular.com/r/Fp2C4ykmpZ))
- `\d+` 1 or more digits ([see demo](http://rubular.com/r/xFb8R6xLgW))

The call to `replaceAll()` trims leading digits from the expression, so you don't get a blank as the first operator.